# Do you need to check for stationarity before using auto.arima()?

Tags: r, time-series, python, arima, stationarity

My question is straightforward: Do you need to check for stationarity (and correct for non-stationarity, if it is the case) before using a function like `auto.arima()` (R) o `auto_arima()` (Python)?

I know that, to work with ARIMA models, your series should be stationary. But a function like `auto.arima` internally check for stationarity (and correct for non-stationarity, if it is the case, by taking differences), so I don't see the need to check for stationarity in this case.

Thanks,

Alejandro.

Comment: Indeed, if the package checks it for you, you need not do it. You might ask if the way the package does it (I am not sure precisely how) is the best way to do it - e.g., an ADF test might still be informative.

Comment: @ChristophHanck if I understand correctly, they use the KPSS test to determine the number of differences needed.